# Unsupported UTF-8 sequence length when > encoding string. default_handler=str does not work

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to write a Dataframe to json file with

`tempfile.write(bytes(df.to_json(orient="records", lines=True, default_handler=str ),encoding="utf-8"))`

but i get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/len/.virtualenvs/normalizer/bin/solute-tank-check-feed-updates", line 7, in <module>
    exec(compile(f.read(), __file__, 'exec'))
                 │         └ '/home/len/GIT/solute/backend/solute-tank-importer/scripts/solute-tank-check-feed-updates'
                 └ <_io.TextIOWrapper name='/home/len/GIT/solute/backend/solute-tank-importer/scripts/solute-tank-check-feed-updates' mode='r' enco...
  File "/home/len/GIT/solute/backend/solute-tank-importer/scripts/solute-tank-check-feed-updates", line 129, in <module>
    cli()  # pylint: disable=no-value-for-parameter
    └ <Command cli>
  File "/home/len/.virtualenvs/normalizer/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1130, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
           │          │       └ {}
           │          └ ()
           └ <Command cli>
  File "/home/len/GIT/solute/infrastructure/python-solute/solute/click.py", line 670, in main
    return super().main(*args, **kwargs)
                         │       └ {'obj': {'checker': None}}
                         └ ()
  File "/home/len/.virtualenvs/normalizer/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1055, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
         │           └ <click.core.Context object at 0x7fb1d930e9d0>
         └ <Command cli>
  File "/home/len/GIT/solute/infrastructure/python-solute/solute/click.py", line 658, in invoke
    return super().invoke(ctx, **kwargs)
                          │      └ {}
                          └ <click.core.Context object at 0x7fb1d930e9d0>
  File "/home/len/.virtualenvs/normalizer/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1404, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
           │          │                └ <click.core.Context object at 0x7fb1d930e9d0>
           │          └ <Command cli>
           └ <click.core.Context object at 0x7fb1d930e9d0>
  File "/home/len/.virtualenvs/normalizer/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 760, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
                       │       └ {'feed_id': 1557, 'options': '{}', 'state': None, 'max_imports': None, 'dryrun': False, 'profile': None}
                       └ ()
  File "/home/len/GIT/solute/infrastructure/python-solute/solute/click.py", line 559, in handle_exceptions
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
           │  │       └ {'feed_id': 1557, 'options': '{}', 'state': None, 'max_imports': None, 'dryrun': False, 'profile': None}
           │  └ ()
           └ <function cli at 0x7fb1d930f200>
  File "/home/len/.virtualenvs/normalizer/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 26, in new_func
    return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
           │ │                       │       └ {'feed_id': 1557, 'options': '{}', 'state': None, 'max_imports': None, 'dryrun': False, 'profile': None}
           │ │                       └ ()
           │ └ <function get_current_context at 0x7fb1da2ee8c0>
           └ <function CheckHook.decorate.<locals>.handle_exceptions at 0x7fb1d930f9e0>
  File "/home/len/GIT/solute/infrastructure/python-solute/solute/click.py", line 512, in handle_exceptions
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
           │  │       └ {'feed_id': 1557, 'options': '{}', 'state': None, 'max_imports': None, 'dryrun': False, 'profile': None}
           │  └ ()
           └ <function cli at 0x7fb1d71c2440>
  File "/home/len/GIT/solute/backend/solute-tank-importer/scripts/solute-tank-check-feed-updates", line 86, in cli
    updates, state = importer.check_for_updates(information["update_state"])
             │       │                          └ {'id': 1557, 'name': 'Passiontec.de', 'workers': 1, 'options': {'id': 1842, 'url': 'https://www.passiontec.de/download/billiger/...
             │       └ <solute.tank.importer.shop_offers_raw.ShopOffersDataRaw object at 0x7fb1d79a6090>
             └ None
  File "/home/len/GIT/solute/backend/solute-tank-importer/solute/tank/importer/shop_offers_raw.py", line 364, in check_for_updates
    tempfile,
    └ <_io.BufferedRandom name='/tmp/tmpnikqp_xd'>
  File "/home/len/GIT/solute/backend/solute-tank-importer/solute/tank/importer/shop_offers_raw.py", line 250, in _parse_raw_data
    lines=True,
  File "/home/len/.virtualenvs/normalizer/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1891, in to_json
    index=index)
  File "/home/len/.virtualenvs/normalizer/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/json/json.py", line 58, in to_json
    index=index).write()
  File "/home/len/.virtualenvs/normalizer/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/json/json.py", line 101, in write
    self.date_format == 'iso', self.default_handler)
  File "/home/len/.virtualenvs/normalizer/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/json/json.py", line 156, in _write
    iso_dates, default_handler)
File "/home/len/.virtualenvs/normalizer/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/json/json.py", line 112, in _write
    default_handler=default_handler
    │               └ <class 'str'>
    └ <class 'str'>
OverflowError: Unsupported UTF-8 sequence length when encoding string
```

In every other post the error was fixed with adding the `default_handler=str`, but it gives the same error for me. I have a suspicion that i did something wrong while reading the Dataframe, because the only file where i get this error uses multichar delimiters. This is my reading function:

```
def _get_df_from_csv(
    delimiter,
    encoding,
    header,
    id_column_renamed,
    input_file,
    nrows,
    quotechar,
    trailing_delimiter,
    quoting=None,
    doublequote=None,
    chunksize=None,
):
    input_file.seek(0)
    parameters = dict(
        sep=delimiter,
        header=header,
        encoding=encoding,
        error_bad_lines=False,
        nrows=nrows,
        dtype=str,
    )

    if len(delimiter) > 1:
        parameters["engine"] = 'python'
        test_data = input_file.readline()
        input_file.seek(0)
        if isinstance(test_data, bytes):
            parameters["sep"] = delimiter.encode(encoding=encoding)
    if trailing_delimiter:
        parameters["index_col"] = False
    if quotechar:
        parameters["quotechar"] = quotechar
    if quoting is not None:
        parameters["quoting"] = quoting
    if doublequote is not None:
        parameters["doublequote"] = doublequote
    if chunksize is not None:
        parameters["chunksize"] = chunksize

    return _pandas.read_csv(input_file, **parameters)
```

and the Delimiter in question would be "||". I know that pandas uses regular expressions for multichar delimiters, so in this case the read_csv gets `parameters["sep"]=r"\|\|"` from my program.

EDIT: I tried using chunksize to limit the position of the error,but it already breaks in the first rows. so here is the header and first 2 rows decoded with 'ISO-8859-1':

```
Hersteller||Herstellernummer||Artikel||Preis||Verfügbarkeit||Deeplink||Versandkosten Vorauskasse||Versandkosten Nachnahme||Versandkosten Kreditkarte||EAN||Artikelbeschreibung||Klasse||Währung||Artnr||Abbildung||Grundpreis||Energieffiezienzklasse||Versandkosten Finanzierung||Versandkosten Sofortüberweisung||Versandkosten PayPal||Gruppe||Hersteller

Makita||DHP481RTJ||Makita DHP481RTJ 2x 5Ah Akku im MAKPAC||344.44||Lagernd, ca. 1 Werktage||https://www.passiontec.de/makita-dhp481rtj-2x-5ah-akku.html?ref_id=Billiger&language=de&pk_campaign=Billiger&pk_source=billiger&pk_medium=cpc&pk_content=Akku-Schlagbohrschrauber||2.95||2.95||2.95||0088381674904||Makita DHP481RTJ 2x 5Ah Akku im MAKPAC||Werkzeuge||EUR||90002335||https://www.passiontec.de/images/extern/artikel/90002335.jpg||||||2.95||2.95||2.95||Akku-Schlagbohrschrauber||Makita

Makita||DTD153RTJ||Makita DTD129RTJ 2x 5Ah Akku im MAKPAC, DTD153RTJ||282.82||Lagernd, ca. 1 Werktage||https://www.passiontec.de/makita-dtd129rtj-2x-5ah-akku.html?ref_id=Billiger&language=de&pk_campaign=Billiger&pk_source=billiger&pk_medium=cpc&pk_content=Akku-Schlagschrauber||2.95||2.95||2.95||0088381686235||Makita DTD129RTJ 2x 5Ah Akku im MAKPAC, DTD153RTJ||Werkzeuge||EUR||90002336||https://www.passiontec.de/images/extern/artikel/90002336.jpg||||||2.95||2.95||2.95||Akku-Schlagschrauber||Makitahere
```

UPDATE: It seems to have been a Problem with an older pandas version not working as expected with multichar delimiters. I upgraded form Version 0.23 to 1.1 and it fixed the issue.

Comment: Probably your input file contains something invalid, but you are not showing us what. Please review https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379403/problematic-questions-about-decoding-errors

Comment: Thank you for your comment, i edited my question to be more insightful i hope.

Comment: If your data is actually using the encoding `iso-8859-1` then reading it as UTF-8 is obviously wrong, and the error message is telling you that.

Comment: Iam not reading it as UTF-8, iam reading it with ```iso-8859-1``` and want to write it as a json file in UTF-8 after that. The code alrdy fails for ``` df.to_json(orient="records", lines=True, default_handler=str )``` without the casting to bytes and writing part.

Comment: Can you please [edit] to provide the exact traceback? Also probably show how you are opening the file, and review [mre] - probably remove a lot of irrelevant code and focus on the smallest possible test case which will reproduce your problem.

Comment: Weirdly enough while i tried to build a minimal reproducible example, i removed most of the data and it just worked, so i used "Ctrl + Z" to undo my changes, but the code still ran. 
I had to redownload the file to reproduce the error again. I then removed the last line and undid my changes instantly and it worked again. Iam not sure what causes this.

Comment: The traceback contains a lot of fluff from what looks like VSCode and other wrapping; in fact, I'm not sure it's complaining about the code in the question at all. If you can repro on the command line, that should provide a much more focused and useful traceback.

Comment: It sounds like an encoding or line ending issue with the source data file, if you can resolve the issue by simply saving it locally in an editor.